# Background image of table row cutting itself into half

Tags: css, background-image

I have table row class named `logo` with attributes

`.logo 
{
    background: url("img/logo.png") no-repeat left top !important; 
}`

Now I do get an image on top left on every row, but what I am trying to accomplish here is to move image out of `table row` such that half of the image is in `` `table `` and half of it outside the table.

I changed the my class to

`.logo 
{
    background: url("img/logo.png") no-repeat -12px top !important; 
}`

and get half of the image in table row but the part of image outside the table disappears (cant see it).

I have tried using `z-index`, `position` properties but nothing works. Can someone guide me in right direction on how i can get required behaviour?

**NB:** testing it in Firefix 20.0.1
Thanks

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood some CSS stuff, can you make an example at jsfiddle.net and _please_ don't use `!important` unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: Do you want the background for some element to appear somewhere else than where the element itself is? That won't work. Cut the picture in half and use half of it as the background of whatever is to the left of the table.

Comment: Of course a background image _does not_ get displayed outside of the element’s dimensions … D’oh!

Comment: I was trying to replicate behaviour used by some popular websites like ebay where they have some logo on a picture which is half on picture and half outside. Anyway, can anyone suggest any website where i can upload any pic (i was creating a fiddle for my problem but got struck as i need it to reference to some pic)

Comment: @Jay You can use lorempixel.com to use dummy images for your code ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with this trick: you will never see the background because it don't have space to show... Solution naturally pass to set a padding in the `<tr>` to make that padding show the background image. But, `<tr>` only gain padding if you set the `display` to `display:block;`.

I finally use this code:

```
.logo {
   background:url(whatever.jpg) no-repeat -12px top;
   display:block;
   padding-left:12px;
}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHkmy/2/).

Hope this helps!